# $add operation returns null value

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with document structure :

```
 {
  'year' : 2014,
  'month' : 1
 }
```

I am executing the following operation :

```
db.collname.aggregate(
                        [
                           {
                             $project : {
                                    'year100' : {$multiply : ["$year" , 100]},
                                    'result' : { '$add' : ['$year100', '$month'] }       
                                        }
                           }
                        ]
                      );
```

I get the following result :

```
 {
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5563596c515a88832210f0e4"),
        "year100" : 201400.0000000000000000,
        "result" : null
    },
}
```

Why is add operation returuning null value as against to actual value ? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDb not allow to used same fields in project to arithmetic operation instead of one `$project` used two different `projects` like this :

```
db.collname.aggregate({ $project : { 'year100' : {$multiply : ["$year" , 100]} ,"month":"$month"} },{"$project":{"year100":1,"result":{"$add":["$year100","$month"]}}})
```

Comment: Apparently, it is not the case that MongoDB does not allow what you described. The problem is that `$project` works on the fields of the input document, which by the moment of applying `$project` does not yet have the `year100` field. Thus, the `null` value ;)